# Is there a way to easily start and manage an android project and it's dependancies?

Tags: android, dependencies, workflow

I am looking for an easy and somewhat automated way of starting and managing an Android project. I have been working on a few projects here and there and have found that a good amount of the time dependencies are a pain point. I am currently using Eclipse and looking into Maven. Which from what I understand is a dependency manager. I would greatly appreciate if anyone could provide suggestions on good process or tools to make setup and initialization less of a hassle. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're starting to learn Android, don't waste your time with learning [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) / the [Android Maven plugin](http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/), but go for [Gradle](http://gradle.org/) / the [Gradle plugin for Android](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/plugin-for-gradle.html) and [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) as the IDE. Both Maven and Gradle are dependency managers (and build systems).

Google's [docs on the new Gradle build system](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) contain a section about [why Gradle](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Why-Gradle-) was chosen, and [examples about how to manage dependencies](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Remote-artifacts). Basically, all you need to do is to add repositories and an compile dependencies like

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2'
}

android {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Great thank you. Just so I know what makes Gradle preferable to Maven? Is it that it is easier for beginners, or just a better system altogether?

Comment: For one thing, it's the build system endorsed by Google, and the "official" successor the of legacy Ant / Eclipse ADT build system. Secondly, Gradle uses Groovy as a Domain Specific Language (DSL) for scripting, which IMO is much clearer, more flexible and easier to learn than Maven XML.

Comment: Awesome thanks! trying to develop good habits and practices early on. You have been very helpful much appreciated.